# drawing lines on circle segments in paperjs

Tags: javascript, geometry, paperjs

I'm trying to make the line point to the center of the circle -or the circular shape- and in the code below they obviously do not. They are initialized in the proper position but they end at the wrong spot. Should be fairly easy but I couldn't crack it. How do I achieve this?

```
var path = new Path.RegularPolygon({
  center: [100, 100],
  radius: 50,
  sides: 10
});
path.style = {
  fillColor: 'red',
  strokeColor: null
}
path.selected = true;

for(var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++){
  spike = new Path();
  spike.add(new Point(path.segments[i].point.x, path.segments[i].point.y));
  spike.add(new Point(path.segments[i].point.x + 10, path.segments[i].point.y + 10));
  spike.strokeColor = 'black';
  spike.strokeWidth = 2.5;
}
```

this is what comes out of it:

[image: this is what comes out of it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know any paper.js, but as far as math goes, here's an attempt:

```
var ctr = {x: 100.0, y: 100.0};
var rad = 50.0;
var spikeLen = 10; 

for(var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++){
  spike = new Path();
  var p = { 
    x: path.segments[i].point.x,
    y: path.segments[i].point.y
  };
  spike.add(new Point(p.x, p.y));
  spike.add(new Point(p.x - spikeLen*(ctr.x-p.x)/rad, p.y - spikeLen*(ctr.y-p.y)/rad);
  spike.strokeColor = 'black';
  spike.strokeWidth = 2.5;
}
```

Comment: i think i poorly explained. my aim was to make them go outwardly, not to the center. otherwise the result is  the same as the answer above.

Comment: beautiful. thanx a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Set another path say path1 of the same shape with radius of 40 (50 - 10 = 40. Since you want the spike of 10) The draw the spike from path to path1 for each of the points

The final code is as follows

```
var path = new Path.RegularPolygon({
  center: [100, 100],
  radius: 50,
  sides: 10
});
path.style = {
  fillColor: 'red',
  strokeColor: null
}
path.selected = true;

/* Add path1  */
var path1 = new Path.RegularPolygon({
  center: [100, 100],
  radius: 40,  // 50 -10 =40
  sides: 10
});
path1.style = {
  strokeColor: 'red'
}

for(var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++){
  spike = new Path();
  spike.add(new Point(path.segments[i].point.x,    path.segments[i].point.y));

  /* end point is on path1 */
  spike.add(new Point(path1.segments[i].point.x ,  path1.segments[i].point.y));

  spike.strokeColor = 'black';
  spike.strokeWidth = 2.5;
}
```

Comment: this was also my solution to make it work eventually. but i didn't find it too versatile.